# What are the differences between BPMN and CMMN?

Tags: modeling, bpmn

Although BPMN and CMMN have different symbols, they both seem to represent the activities that happen in a scenario somehow. Are the two standards interchangeable (at least in some situations)? If not, when should I use BPMN / CMMN?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business process modelling standards.

Comment: @Suncatcher this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: That is exactly why [Quora rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298936/911419), as you spend your time on question, not arguing why your question is acceptable for the site :)

Answer (score 4):

BPMN is good for making models of structured business processes that, despite some variations, share the same structure and can possibly be automated. BPMN can be used for

1. Describing/documenting established business processes.
2. Designing new business processes.
3. Defining automated business processes that can be enacted by a business process engine.

CMMN is good for making "case management" models, which describe semi-structured business processes that cannot be automated.

See also these [presentation slides](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM4vHH-fbZAhXHwBQKHWzPB7EQFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.slideshare.net%2Fdgagne%2Fbpmncmmndmn-an-intro-to-the-triple-crown-of-process-improvement-standards-denis-gagne&usg=AOvVaw0mz1HQHE67OZPQtpRzq7dC).